# Python: List.Index(x), fails to find value when list is sliced after position 0

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list, slice

Why is list.index(x) not finding a match when I slice the index after position 0?

This statement correctly sets closed_order = 0.

```
closed_order = trades[:][0].index(strategy)
```

But the statement below cannot find the value.  I would expect it to return 4.

```
closed_order = trades[2:][0].index(strategy)
```

The if statement also correctly finds the match.

The entire code is shown below.

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 2

trades = [['shp_str_sl_17_(Clsd Prft)', '12/18/11', Decimal('4.66')],
          ['shp_str_sl_17_(Re)', '12/18/11', Decimal('4.61')],
          ['shp_str_sl_17_(Re)', '1/22/12', Decimal('5.62')],
          ['shp_str_sl_17_(OBV X^)', '1/29/12', Decimal('6.63')],
          ['shp_str_sl_17_(Clsd Prft)', '3/11/12', Decimal('6.84')],
          ['shp_str_sl_17_(UDR 0^)', '7/29/12', Decimal('5.03')],
          ['shp_str_sl_17_(Clsd Prft)', '10/28/12', Decimal('5.60')]]

strategy = 'shp_str_sl_17_(Clsd Prft)'
if trades[4][0] == strategy:
        print "match found"

closed_order = trades[2:][0].index(strategy)
print "closed_order=",closed_order
```

I am new to Python and appreciate the help.
Thank you.
Best regards,
Sanjay

Comment: You should look at the value `trades[2:][0]` (e.g. print it, or use an interactive python or ipython shell).  Is it what you expect?

Comment: What are you expecting `trades[2:][0]` to give you?  Why do you expect `trades[2:][0].index(strategy)` to give you 4?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes! That and BrenBarn's answer helped to clarify the meaning of [2:][0].  Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[2:]` means "give me elements from 2 onward".  `[0]` means "give me the first element".  So `trades[2:][0]` means "give me the first element of the elements from 2 onward" -- which is the same as just `trades[2]`.  That does not contain your `strategy`.

Likewise, in your first example, `trades[:][0]` is the same as `trades[0]`.  This just happens to work for your example because `trades[0]` does contain your targeted strategy.

It's not clear what you think `trades[2:][0]` does, but maybe you're thinking that that the `[0]` means "give me the first element of each of the sub-lists".  But that's not what it means.  If you want that you'd have to use a list comprehension:

```
[sub_list[0] for sub_list in trades[2:]].index(strategy)
```

However, this will not give you 4, but 2, because by slicing `trades` you have changed where your new list starts.  The element that used to be at position 4 is now at position 2, because you sliced 2 elements off at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  That's pretty astute that you should figure out what my intention is.